# How to fix IntelliSense color-coding issue in VS Code after a property declaration in a Blazor component

Tags: visual-studio-code, blazor, intellisense

In a Blazor project on a razor page after a property declared all the code coloring below changes:
types are no longer marked with blue, [Parameter] also not green.
[(issue view)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPL3W.jpg)

Is it my declaration somehow wrong?
Is there any way to fix this issue?

code runs with no issues.
Thanks!

Placed declaration in different parts of the component and on separate @code{} section - same behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the Language Mode from `ASP.NET Razor` to `Razor`:
[image]

Comment: although this shall work but it breaks the intellisense for some external components.